# PHP preg_replace everything but text in brackets

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace every match of the following string with `''` but leave the curly brackets and the text inside.  There is also text surrounding the span elements, and there are multiple tags with tag_item varying and Tag title varying.

Example string:

```
Text text text text 
<span contenteditable="false" data-tag="{{tag_item}}">Tag Title</span>
Text text text text 
<span contenteditable="false" data-tag="{{tag_item2}}">Tag Title2</span>
Text text text text
```

And I would like it to become:

```
Text text text text 
{{tag_item}}
Text text text text 
{{tag_item2}}
Text text text text
```

Here is what I have so far, and it is not working:

```
$message = preg_replace('/" contenteditable="false">(.*)<\/span>/i', '', $message);

$message = str_replace('<span data-tag="', '', $message);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that example string the only content? Mention a bit more context / use case. Wouldn't just searching for `{{tags}}` and throwing everything else away be simpler?

Comment: @mario, see updated question.  There will be text surrounding the spans and there will be multiple spans.

Comment: Are there other tags besides `<span ..` ?

Comment: Yes there can be p tags, font tags, etc.  It's being used inside ckeditor if that helps for the types of available tags that are in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$m = preg_replace ('/<span contenteditable="false" data-tag=\"/i','',$message);
$answer = preg_replace ('/\">.*?<\/span>/i', '' ,$m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

$message = preg_replace('/.*data-tag="(.*)".*/', '$1', $message);

Answer (score 0):

Well, then do it in one regex:

```
= preg_replace("#
    <(\w+) [^>]* (\{\{\w+\}\}) [^>]*>
    (.*?)
    </\1>
#smix", "$2 $3", $src)
```

This just looks for your {{tag}} and everything whatever just with it `$2` and the text `$3` between angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Regex to parse HTML, use the DOM.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
Text text text text 
<span contenteditable="false" data-tag="{{tag_item}}">Tag Title</span>
Text text text text 
<span contenteditable="false" data-tag="{{tag_item2}}">Tag Title2</span>
Text text text text 
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$expression = '//text()[not(parent::*[@data-tag])]|//*[@data-tag]/@data-tag';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  switch ($node->nodeType) {
  case XML_TEXT_NODE :
    echo $node->nodeValue;
    break;
  case XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE :
    echo $node->value;
    break;
  }
}
```

### The Expression

The Xpath expression matches all text nodes, if the parent is not an element with a data-tag attribute and all data-tag attributes.

Match all text nodes at any position in the DOM:

```
//text()
```

Limit that to the nodes where the parent has no "data-tag" attribute

```
[not(parent::*[@data-tag])]
```

Or

```
|
```

Select all data-tag attributes

```
@data-tag
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, maybe this can be your solution

```php
$message = preg_replace('/<\w+\s+contenteditable="false"\s+data-tag="({{.*}})">.*<\/\w+>/imsU', '$1', $message);
```

The option "U" is for Ungreedy and try to find the shortest occurence instead of the longest for all countable elements (I mean elements which are followed by "?", "+" or "*").

You can have more options on this page: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php